# Same code in new project says angular is not defined

Tags: angularjs

I have two projects in express with exact same code. One project works fine but the other project says

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
          ^
```

**ERROR**

> ReferenceError: angular is not defined.

What might be the issue?

Comment: I think you need to include Angular Javascript lib file to run project. That may be missing in you another project.

Comment: please provide your html also

Comment: this is what i have used in both the files . <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that angular is not defined. Most likely you html is missing the script tags for including the angular code.

Comment: i have copy pasted the code from the one that is working and i still face that issue

Comment: Did you also paste the code for the html you are using (containing the <script src= "ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/… )? Is it possible that the html is somehow not valid, therefore not loading the angular js referenced in the script tag? Posting html would be helpful.